# Kentico 12 Service Pack - MVC site only redirects to Admin site login page

Tags: kentico-12, kentico-mvc

I have a site I'm building in Kentico 12 MVC. I just upgraded the admin backend app and my MVC app to the Kentico 12 Service Pack (hotfix 12.29).

Now my MVC app only redirects to the admin app login page. I removed the admin redirect route mapping from my app, and this still happens. The site was working fine before the hotfix, now I can't even see the home page.

Because the site is in early development, I didn't backup anything prior to applying the hotfix. Nonetheless, redoing things from scratch would be non-trivial. Lesson learned.

Okay, this is really weird. I shut down the admin site in IIS and its app pool. Still getting the login screen. The admin logon screen is coming from inside the <s>house</s> website.

For clarity, I have two sites: `mysite.local` (MVC app) and `admin-mysite.local` (stock Kentico instance). I stopped `admin-mysite.local` and its app pool in IIS. When I visit `mysite.local` it looks and acts just like a Kentico admin instance, complete with the admin login screen. I tried logging in and, it's working just like a Kentico admin site should, taking me to `mysite.local/` This is extremely bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

The hotfix executable changed my MVC site's physical path to that of the admin site. I changed it back to the path for the MVC app and now I'm back on track.

Is this normal behavior? Maybe it was supposed to get changed back by the hotfix .exe and there was a hiccup? Whatever, I fixed it. Hopefully this saves someone else several hours of wtf in the future.